# Cancellation Token Disposed Exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I had this piece of code that initially worked fine. However, After adding it to a class where I store my methods that are reused, it keeps failing. The exception that is caught states that the CancellationTokenSource has been Disposed. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have tried creating a new client and Adding CancellationToken.None to the PutAsync() method from HTTPClient Class but it still fails with the CancellationTokenSource Disposed exception.

```
public async void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        string storeId = "";

        try
        {
            var storeData = JObject.Parse(Connect.Json).SelectToken("store").ToString();

            var stores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Store>>(storeData);

            var store = stores[0];

            storeId = store.Id;

            store.Products.Add(product);

            ProdInfo info = new Info();

            foreach(Product p in store.Products)
            {
                info.AddedProducts =  + p.Id;
            }

            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);

            using (Connect.Client)
            using (var response = await Connect.Client.PutAsync(_url + "/stores/" + storeId, new StringContent(content)))
            {
                var cont = response.Content;
                string result = await cont.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if ((int)response.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                    this.JobResult = result;
                    //this.JobResult = "Store has been successfully updated";
                }
                else
                {
                    this.JobResult = result;
                    //this.JobResult = "Store was not updated!";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //this.JobResult = "Store has not been updated due to an error.";
            this.JobResult = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is Connect.Client?

Comment: Its a class I created that stores an HTTP Client and exposes it as a property.

Comment: If it only “stores” an `HttpClient`, rather than creates a new only each time, the second time through that method it will already be disposed (from the `using` on the first time through).

Comment: @sellotape I see. Will modify the code to see what results I get.

Comment: In general, short lived objects are easier to maintain. Client looks like a static property. Statics have their use, but if you can avoid them, do so.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR will do. Thanks for the advice. Will update here once I make the changes.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR - in general, but `HttpClient` is an exception; it should be [long-lived and reused](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I made some changes to the Connect Class and all is well now. The HttpClient was being disposed before I finished using it. @sellotape that documentation called long-lived and reused will definitely help with this process.

Comment: If you solved this issue, please post your solution as answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by simple removing 'using(Connect.Client)' from all of my methods. As @sellotape stated, They were disposing of the HttpClient before I was able to use it again. Thank you all for your contributions.